# sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I'm having issues trying to install ***sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master*** on **Symfony3**, I'm getting this error 
**sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master]**

Does anybody expire the same problem? How to fix it?

Here is my composer.json require

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.3.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "dev-master",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.2.7",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.10",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FOS User 2.x is not stable for SF3. Until FOS User won't release the 2.x stable version, Sonata User Bundle won't be compatible.

Please, check the [issue on github](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/322)

Answer (score 0):

sonata-user-bundle does NOT have any version compatible with Symfony 3, that is your problem.

The conflict probably comes from the fact that 
doctrine-orm-admin-bundle requires a symfony 3.x version of sonata admin while user-bundle requires a symfony 2.8 version.